# SQL select if row into joined table is empty

Tags: sql

Have 2 tables T1 and T2
Does sql has any variants select all rows from T1 if into T2 related row does not exists  ? without JoinLeft

for example

```
table user
id---name
1     A
2     B

task
id----idUser
1       1
```

result == `2,B`
BR!

Comment: What is the reason of not using Leftjoin? you could achieve this by left join easily

Comment: I think this query wont work when you have multiple record of id=2 in first table with different username

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach is to use `not in`:

```
select u.*
from user u
where u.id not in (select iduser from task);
```

However, `not exists` has better semantics because it handles `NULL` values more intuitively:

```
select u.*
from user u
where not exists (select 1 from task t where t.iduser = u.id);
```